# Prevent Dismissal of UIViewController Presented with presentViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have two UIViewControllers in my app. Performing an action on UIViewControllerA loads UIViewControllerB or UIViewControllerC with no problem.

```
let destinationViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UIVCB") as! ViewControllerB
destinationViewController.results = result
self.presentViewController(destinationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil )
```

(I want to present the second view controller (B or C) *modally* because I want the user to deal with something there and *not* return to UIViewControllerA until he or she has done so.)

The problem is that clicking *anywhere* on UIViewControllerB or UIViewControllerC returns the user to UIViewControllerA. At first I thought I was instantiating these incorrectly, but someone has answered here and indicated that is not the problem. (And I find it hard to believe the problem is with code in B or C because it's affecting both of them.)

I have found dozens (hundreds?) of search results detailing how to *dismiss* a presented viewcontroller, but I can't seem to find any explaining how to *prevent* dismissing one.

Am I wrong to be using presentViewController() this way to load the second view? Or am I simply missing something obvious to prevent the second controller being dismissed by clicking anywhere on the screen?

**Update:** If I use this code to instantiate B or C, the problem of "clicking anywhere to dismiss" goes away:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController( destinationViewController, animated: true )
```

But I was under the assumption that I shouldn't be invoking the navigationController and / or pushing and popping because B and C are supposed to be modal and outside the navigation stack.

Comment: When you want to dismiss a modal controller you should use dismissViewControllerAnimated not popViewController . As of your issue you should provide more details or code of your controller. By default tapping in viewController doesn't dismiss the controller.

Comment: @stefos You want the entire code of the second view controller? Okay, I will update my question with that.
But in general you believe I am *presenting* my second view controller correctly.

Comment: Yes, that's the correct way of presenting a controller. To dismiss the second controller  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(...) .

Comment: I just reviewed the code and realize now that it can't be a problem with the second view controller, because -- I left this part out of my original question -- clicking the button on the first view controller instantiates one of two different view controllers (B, C) depending on the situation, and both B and C have the problem of getting dismissed regardless of where they're clicked.